# SupportfragmentManager becomes null android kotlin

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to launch a dialogFragment from onPostExecute but the supportFragmentManager for some reason returns null. I have tried launching the dialogFragment from main activity and other fragments and it works perfectly but I am not able to launch it from AsyncTask. Here is the AsyncTask:-

```
class SubscribeTask: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    var mContext: Context
    var mTextView_temp: TextView
    var mTextView_humidity: TextView
    var mWeather_image: ImageView
    var mMessage: JsonObject
    var mResult = JsonObject()
    var mTemp: String = ""
    var mHumidity: String = ""
    var mLdr: Boolean = true
    var mRain: Boolean = false
    var mWeather: Int = 0
    var tester: Boolean = false
    var mFire: Boolean = false

    constructor(context: Context, textView_temp: TextView, textView_humidity: TextView, weather_image: ImageView, message: PNMessageResult){
        mContext = context
        mMessage = message.message.asJsonObject
        mTextView_temp = textView_temp
        mTextView_humidity = textView_humidity
        mWeather_image = weather_image
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Void? {
        if (mMessage.has("pi")){
            mResult = mMessage.getAsJsonObject("pi")
            mTemp = mResult.get("temp").asString
            mHumidity = mResult.get("humidity").asString
            mLdr = mResult.get("ldr").asBoolean
            mRain = mResult.get("rain").asBoolean
            mFire = mResult.get("fire").asBoolean
            tester = true
            if(mRain){
              mWeather = R.drawable.rainy
            }else if(mLdr){
                mWeather = R.drawable.suny
            }else{
                mWeather = R.drawable.cloudyy
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        if(tester) {
            mTextView_temp.text = mTemp
            mTextView_humidity.text = mHumidity
            mWeather_image.setImageResource(mWeather)
            if(mFire){
                MainActivity().showAlertDialog("Fire", "There might be a fire in the house", R.drawable.house_fire, "Stop Alarm")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the showAlertDialog() function:-

```
fun showAlertDialog(title: String, content: String, imageid: Int, button: String){
        val fm = supportFragmentManager
        val alertDialogFragment = AlertFragment(title, content, imageid, button).newInstance(title, content, imageid, button)
        alertDialogFragment.show(fm, "fragment_alert")
    }
```

Here is the dialogFragment:-

```
class AlertFragment(val mTitle: String, val mContent: String, val mImageId: Int, val mButton: String) : DialogFragment() {

    fun newInstance(title: String, content: String, imageid: Int, button: String): AlertFragment {
        val alertfrag = AlertFragment(title, content, imageid, button)
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString("title", title)
        alertfrag.arguments = args
        return alertfrag
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        title.text = mTitle
        alertContent.text = mContent
        alertImageId.setImageResource(mImageId)
        alertButton.text = mButton
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me. Answers in Java are also okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Observer Pattern for this.

Create a interface like that

```
interface myExecListener {
 fun onFinish(title: String, content: String, imageid: Int, button: 
 String)
 }
```

Add this lines into SubscribeTask

```
class SubscribeTask: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
 var listener: myExecListener? = null

  fun exec(listener: myExecListener){
    this.listener = listener
    this.execute()
  }

  override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {


    return null
  }

  override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    listener?.onFinish("Fire", "There might be a fire in the house", 333, "Stop Alarm")
  }
 }
```

And execute in your activity

```
SubscribeTask().exec(object : myExecListener{
  override fun onFinish(title: String, content: String, imageid: Int, button: String) {
    println("Observer triggered")
    showAlertDialog(title, content, imageid, button)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `postExecute` function you have the following code:

```
MainActivity().showAlertDialog(...)
```

This **creates** a new activity object which is definitely not what should be done. Since that object is newly created and not properly initialized by android, internal objects like the supportFragmentManager are not initialized, resulting in the `null` you're seeing.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Generally people store a `WeakReference` of the parent activity in the `AsyncTask`, then access that reference in `postExecute` if they need to call something on the activity.